# Show that $(\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n}+(\sqrt{3}-1)^{2n}$ and $(\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n+1}+(1-\sqrt{3})^{2n+1}$.........?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, binomial-theorem

**Show that $(\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n}+(\sqrt{3}-1)^{2n}$ and $(\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n+1}+(1-\sqrt{3})^{2n+1}$ are both divisible by $2^{n+1}$. Is this the highest power of $2$ dividing either of the numbers?**

I am not well versed with binomial theorem hence I am not able to proceed. I am also interested in the different ways this problem can be solved.

*Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: Hint: $a_n = (1+\sqrt{3})^n + (1-\sqrt{3})^n$ satisfies $a_{n+2} = 2a_{n+1} + 2a_n$

Comment: How do you derive that? I guess we can proceed by induction from here.

Comment: This is because $1 \pm \sqrt{3}$ are roots of $(\lambda - 1)^2 - 3 = \lambda^2 - 2\lambda - 2$.

Comment: @achillehui your wonderful hint could be turned around to an anwer!

Comment: Yes, I would be eager to make it the accepted answer. By the way, how do I find the highest power of 2? I proved the first part by the hint and induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n = (1+\sqrt{3})^n + (1 - \sqrt{3})^n$ for $n \ge 0$.

Since $1 \pm \sqrt{3}$ are roots of $(\lambda - 1)^2 - 3 = \lambda^2 - 2\lambda - 2$, $a_n$ satisfies a recurrence relation:

$$a_{n+2} = 2(a_{n+1} + a_n)$$

Define two auxiliary sequences $b_n, c_n$ by
$\begin{cases}
b_n &= 2^{-(n+1)} a_{2n}\\
c_n &= 2^{-(n+1)} a_{2n+1}
\end{cases}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
b_{n} &= 2^{-(n+1)}a_{2n} = 2^{-n}(a_{2n-1} + a_{2n-2}) = c_{n-1} + b_{n-1}\\
c_{n} &= 2^{-(n+1)}a_{2n+1} = 2^{-n}(a_{2n} + a_{2n-1}) = 2b_n + c_{n-1} = 2b_{n-1} + 3c_{n-1}
\end{align}$$
or in matrix form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}b_n \\ c_n\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}b_{n-1} \\ c_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$$
Since $a_0 = a_1 = 2 \implies b_0 = c_0 = 1$, this leads to following representation of $(a_{2n}, a_{2n+1})$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{2n} \\ a_{2n+1}\end{bmatrix}
= 2^{n+1}\begin{bmatrix}b_n \\ c_n\end{bmatrix}
= 2^{n+1}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}^n \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

From above expression, it is easy to see $(b_n, c_n)$ are integers. This implies $2^{n+1}$ divides both $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$.
In fact, since $c_0 = 1$ is odd and
$$c_{n} = 2b_{n-1} + 3c_{n-1} \equiv c_{n-1} \pmod 2$$
all $c_n$ are odd. From this, we can deduce $2^{n+1}$ is the highest factor of $2$ that divides both $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

From binomial expansion it follows that
$$[(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n]$$ $$=[2^n+{n \choose 2} 2^{n-2} 3+{n \choose 4}2^{n-4} 3^2+...]=2K, K \in N$$
And $$[(2+\sqrt{3})^n-(2-\sqrt{3})^n]$$ $$=2\sqrt{3}[2^{n-1}+{n \choose 1} 2^{n-1}+{n \choose 3}2^{n-3} 3+...]=2\sqrt{3}L, L \in N$$
$$S_1=(1+\sqrt{3})^{2n}+(1-\sqrt{3})^{2n}=2^n[(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n]=2^{n+1} K.$$
$$S_2=(1+\sqrt{3})^{2n+1}+(1-\sqrt{3})^{2n+1}=S_1+2^n \sqrt{3}[(2+\sqrt{3})^{n}-(2-\sqrt{3})^n]=3.2^{n+1}L$$
Hence, both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are divisible by $2^{n+1}$.

By binomial expansio